# Error al generar Base de Datos SQLite android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Creo una tabla con llaves foraneas y me genera error en la ejecucion, no logro entender el error es el siguiente...

```
01-11 08:57:28.821 27100-27100/company.viral.organizadorjec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: company.viral.organizadorjec, PID: 27100
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18798)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18798) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "foreing": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table materias (id integer primary key autoincrement, nombre text, id_profesor integer, id_periodo integer, detalle text, foreign key(id_profesor) references profesores (id),foreing key(id_periodo) references periodo(id))
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1697)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1628)
                                                                                  at company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales.SQLite.onCreate(SQLite.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                                                                                  at company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales.MainActivity.onClickAcepta(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18798) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

aqui van las clases con los metodos involucrados..

Clase de la base de datos..

**SQLite.java**

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by erny on 27/10/2016.
 */

public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //constructor.......
    public SQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }



    //aqui se crea la tabla...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table usuarios (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, clave text)");

        db.execSQL("create table profesores (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, detalle text)");


        db.execSQL("create table materias (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, id_profesor integer, id_periodo integer, detalle text, " +
                "foreign key(id_profesor) references profesores (id)," +
                "foreing key(id_periodo) references periodo(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table periodo (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, id_usuario integer, fechainicio integer, fechacierre integer," +
                "foreing key(id_usuario) references usuarios(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table caracteristicas (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text)");

        db.execSQL("create table asignacion (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "detalle text, id_materia integer, fecha integer, id_periodo integer, id_tarea integer," +
                "foreing key(id_materia) references materias(id)," +
                "foreing key(id_periodo) references periodo(id)," +
                "foreing key(id_tarea) references tarea(id)");

        db.execSQL("create table tarea (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text)");

        db.execSQL("create table caracteristica_profesor (id_profesor integer, id_caracteristica integer," +
                "foreing key(id_profesor) references profesores(id)," +
                "foreing key(id_caracteristica) references caracteristicas(id)");


        db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('0','admin','admin')");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("create table usuarios (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, clave text)");

        db.execSQL("create table profesores (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, detalle text)");


        db.execSQL("create table materias (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, id_profesor integer, id_periodo integer, detalle text, " +
                "foreign key(id_profesor) references profesores (id)," +
                "foreing key(id_periodo) references periodo(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table periodo (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, id_usuario integer, fechainicio integer, fechacierre integer," +
                "foreing key(id_usuario) references usuarios(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table caracteristicas (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text)");

        db.execSQL("create table asignacion (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "detalle text, id_materia integer, fecha integer, id_periodo integer, id_tarea integer," +
                "foreing key(id_materia) references materias(id)," +
                "foreing key(id_periodo) references periodo(id)," +
                "foreing key(id_tarea) references tarea(id)");

        db.execSQL("create table tarea (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text)");

        db.execSQL("create table caracteristica_profesor (id_profesor integer, id_caracteristica integer," +
                "foreing key(id_profesor) references profesores(id)," +
                "foreing key(id_caracteristica) references caracteristicas(id)");


        db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('0','admin','admin')");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;

//aqui empieza...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //creamos variables EditText para capturar los datos
    private EditText aetid,aetpass;
    private Cursor fila;


    //en este metodo SIEMPRE se dibuja la app correspondiente
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //antes de dibujar definimos las variables y a quienes pertecen en el layout

        aetid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etid);
        aetpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpass);

    }

    //creamos los metodos con los que reaccionan los btn (onClick)
    /*metodo para entrar y buscar (en construccion.... explorando metodos)*/

    public void onClickAcepta (View view) {
        String auxn = aetid.getText().toString();
        String auxp = aetpass.getText().toString();

        SQLite admin = new SQLite(this,"administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        fila=bd.rawQuery("select nombre, clave from usuarios where nombre='"+auxn+"'and clave='"+auxp+"'",null);



        if(fila.moveToFirst()==true){

            //capturamos los valores del cursos y lo almacenamos en variable
            String usua=fila.getString(0);
            String pass=fila.getString(1);

            //preguntamos si los datos ingresados son iguales
            if (auxn.equals(usua)&&auxp.equals(pass)){

                //si son iguales entonces vamos a otra ventana
                //Menu es una nueva actividad empty
                Intent ven=new Intent(this,MenuCentral.class);

                startActivity(ven);

                //limpiamos las las cajas de texto
                aetid.setText("");
                aetpass.setText("");

                finish();

            }

        }else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o contraseña erroneo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        bd.close();

    }

    //metodo para entrar a la actividad de registro

    public void onClickRegistro(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Registro.class);
        startActivity(i);

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("¿Desea Salir de la Aplicación?");
        builder.setTitle("Alerta!");
        builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: lo e probado de ambas maneras y no acepta se cierra la app, es decir sin valores puestos y con valores, al igual que al introducir los valores pre-determinados para hacer pruebas que son "admin admin" como clave y usuario

Comment: El problema es al dar click en un boton que llama onClickAcepta(), Pero podrías agregar el LogCat completo para definir con más exactitud el problema? @ErnyjoseHidalgocorrea

Comment: \0/ FELIZ AÑO!! te escribí gracias por ayudarme de nuevo, ya edite, esta todo

Comment: el mismo logcat te esta diciendo donde esta el error ` Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "foreing": syntax error (code 1): `

Comment: esta al crear tu tabla materiasm `foreing key(id_periodo)` deberia decir `foreign key(id_periodo)`, que por lo visto debes aplicarselo a los demas tablas que tenga eso mismo

Comment: Hola @ERnyJOséHIdalgoCOrrea Feliz año!,cambia primeramente lo que comento en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ver tu mensaje de error se encuentra:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "foreing":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table materias (id
>   integer primary key autoincrement, nombre text, id_profesor integer,
>   id_periodo integer, detalle text, foreign key(id_profesor) references
>   profesores (id),foreing key(id_periodo) references periodo(id))

Primeramente cambia la en la creación de tus tablas todos los `foreing` por `foreign`

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Cuando intenta ejecutar el script mediante `db.execSQL()` no reconoce esta palabra y por esa razón se genera error.

Comment: GRACIAS GRACIAS GRACIAS!! e indirectamente me ayudaste a leer mejor los informes de errores!! GRACIAS!!